# Color Logic...again

Tags: pattern, visual

**Find the rule that is all correct on the left side, but none on the right side.**

[image: correction in correction]

Raw text: (**O**range, **Y**ellow, **G**reen, **C**yan)

Left:

```
OGYCO
C
YYGG
GCOOOYGC
CCOCO
YCGCOCY
CCC
COCOCYY
CGCCCG
GG
```

Right:

```
O
GYCY
CGCGCO
CG
OOOCCC
YOOCCOYC
GGCCCCG
GC
YCGOOY
CCCYYY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it’s simply that:

> There are an even total number of orange, green and yellow. Or, equivalently, leaving out cyan leaves an even number of squares.

How I got to this:

> The single cyan and single orange showed that one of those two colours was important in the rule. Looking, there was a lot of cyan, so I decided to see what would happen if I ignored it, giving this answer.

Comment: But the 7th (from top) on the right side has 4 greens?

Comment: @u_ndefined still, 4th from top has zero non-cyan. Zero is even too.

Comment: @Plarsen there isn’t much contrast between the two colours but the fourth and seventh from the top on the right side have one and three greens respectively.

Comment: yes, sure, after the edit that is true. Not what it looked like yesterday (see revisions): https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI6LJ.png